# for loop method for finding non-sequential slots (holes) in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Just as the title says - I'm trying to find the first empty (missing) number (hole) in an array using for-loop **or**, if the array is sequential and starting from 1 through 7 for example, I'll need the next integer after the last array item, in this case 8.

Need only one hole per whole iteration returning the found value.

My logic is ok when it comes to the first condition (array starting with a value higher than 1) but the from the next to conditions the last one is always picked up.

In a nutshell:

- in an array of [2,3,4,5,6,7] I need "1" and I get it;
- in an array of [1,2,3,4,6,7] I need "5" but I get "8".
- in an array of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] I need "8" and I get it.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers;
let hole;

holeFinder()

function holeFinder() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[0] > 1) {
      /*  console.log(numbers[0]) */
      hole = 1;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>1: hole: " + hole;
      return hole;
    }

    if (numbers[i] > 1) {
      if ((numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1]) > 1) {
        hole = (numbers[i - 1] + 1)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>2: hole: " + hole;
        return hole;
      }

      if ((numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1]) == 1) {
        hole = numbers[numbers.length - 1] + 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>3: hole: " + hole;
        return hole;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>for loop method for finding non-sequential slots (holes) in an array</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Gshegosh/e5torn6L/103/)

What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: By far, the best way to find out what's wrong with the code is to use the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser: Set a breakpoint at the start of the function and step through the code statement by statement, watching the variables, etc.

Comment: Seems an odd way to do that; a while loop which exits on the first int that isn’t in `numbers` is one way to solve that with much less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
const arr2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


const findHole = arr => {
 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== i + 1){
    return i + 1
  }
 }
 return arr.length + 1
}

console.log(findHole(arr1))
console.log(findHole(arr2))
console.log(findHole(arr3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a while loop and find the missing number to break the loop.

```js
const one = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7];
const three = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function findHole(numbers) {
  let count = 0;
  let hole = null;

  while (!hole) {
    count++
    const number = count;
    
    // if the array does not contain number, assign the number
    // as the missing hole number
    if (!numbers.includes(number)) {
      hole = number;
    }
  }

  return hole;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "1: hole: " + findHole(one) + '<br>';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "2: hole: " + findHole(two) + '<br>';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "3: hole: " + findHole(three) + '<br>';
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: your solution is sleek using while loop as AD7six commented, though I'll choose R4ncid's answer as it uses my for-loop prerequisite. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You enter the second part of the second if statement

```
if ((numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1]) == 1) {
    hole = numbers[numbers.length - 1] + 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>3: hole: " + hole;
    return hole;
}
```

on the second iteration of the loop, so as long as you don't find the hole at the first index, it will always return the last array element increased by one. You should check this condition only at the last element of your array.

Comment: if you mean this condition

 if ((numbers[numbers.length - 1] - numbers[numbers.length - 2]) == 1) { ....

just before the function closing curly bracket, then you're right as I have checked it.

Thanks.